# ajax request throwing 405 method not found error (Laravel 5)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am making an ajax call from a form to send the checkbox data to a controller. Here is the relevant html code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://192.168.1.25/nonresponsiveurl" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="del_form" id="del_form" name="del_form"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="igr6iMt1WfeZunyG8wpyy1tNK1efgiclyOvZ1hkF">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete Checked Records" onclick="return submitDelForm();">
   <div class="table-responsive shadow-edge-nofill">

    <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
            <td><input id="badURL0" class="bad_url_checkbox" name="bad_url_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2"></td>

    etc....etc.....etc....

    </form>
```

Here is the relevant javascript code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitDelForm(){
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        var form = document.del_form;
        var dataString = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            URL: '/delbadurl',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {'serial_data' : dataString},
            success: function(data){
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is relevant routing:

```
  Route::post('delbadurl','Admin\DashboardController@delBadURL' );
```

I can confirm that CSRF token is being appended to the dataString. The form data is being appended to the dataString as well. However, jquery throws 405 error.

I am using many other similar ajax functions to fetch and send the data. Everything works perfectly except this particular function. Some pointers will be greatly appreciated as I am coming empty handed.

Comment: first of all `405` is not a jQuery error, it's a http error. you most likely get this error because the form-url you use (`http://192.168.1.25/nonresponsiveurl`) does not exist or is not accessible. you are doing nothing to prevent the standard html-submission of the form. so that's what gets you to the `405` page, i guess.

Comment: For the sake of troubleshooting, I suggest you submit the form without AJAX to see what you get...

Comment: does delBadURL exist in your dashbooardController?

Comment: @low_rents, you are perhaps correct. How do I prevent the standard form submission from occuring? All I want to do is pass the form data to jquery script which will pass it to the controller. The jquery script will rebuild the view after controller executes the code.

Answer (score 1):

like I said in my comment, it seems like your form is submitted in the default (HTML) way.

to prevent that you can use jQuery event-handling.
in order to do so you should remove the `onclick` attribute from your `<input type="submit" ...>` at first.
then bind the event handler to the submit-event and prevent the default behavior of the form submission with `preventDefault()`:

```
$("#del_form").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //your ajax code goes here...
});
```

Comment: This method still does not work. I get 405 error POST http://192.168.1.25/dashboard 405 (Method Not Allowed)n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.js:8625n.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8161(anonymous function) @ VM34299:11n.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4430n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.js:4116

Comment: There is no cross-domain request here, so I am not sure about the message.

Comment: @hvs well, i don't know - hard to remote-debug your problem. maybe you can replicate your issue with jsfiddle. and if your error-console tells you that here is a crossdomain-request, there most likely is. consoles never lie ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do 'url':'/some-text/another-text instead of 'url':'some-text/another-text in your Ajax submission.That is ....there is a / before the first url part.This worked for me.